# Что не так с синтаксисом MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, синтаксис

К примеру есть такой SQL запрос, пример:

```
update 
    house_rooms
set 
    is_closed = 1 and is_empty = 1
where
    owner_id = ? and status = ?
```

Создан для примера, искать в нём логику не стоит, проблема в том что он отрабатывает, но ведь не должен же из-за того что в set указан неверный синтаксис, то есть если заменить:

```
set hr.is_closed = 1 and hr.is_empty = 1
```

На строку:

```
set hr.is_closed = 1, hr.is_empty = 1
```

Тогда он выполняется и меняет значения.

Сам вопрос: почему не выдает ошибку, а показывает что запрос отработал?

БД: MariaDB 10.2, но думаю это на ответ не повлияет.

Comment: Правильно через запятую, и у вас оно работает. В чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Что значит "нет результата"? Какой результат Вы ожидаете?

Comment: @YuraIvanov я же написал - "но почему не выдает ошибку, а показывает что запрос отработал"

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ошибку синтаксиса ожидал

Comment: Нет ошибки синтаксиса. Выражение `1 and is_empty = 1` легальное булево выражение и его результат присваивается `is_closed`

Comment: У вас заголовок вопроса ссылается на синтаксис кода, а вопрос об ошибке. Вы что именно хотите?

Comment: @Tivyram зачем сначала отвечать не читая вопрос, потом задавать вопрос?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/44066

Comment: @YuraIvanov спасибо, не знал про это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет ошибки синтаксиса. Выражение `1 and is_empty = 1` легальное булево выражение и его результат присваивается `is_closed`.
Например,

```
select field1 and field2 from t;
```

выдаст результат булевой конъюнкции двух полей.